# Prove that any integer greater than or equal to $7$ can be written as a sum of two relatively prime integers, both greater than $1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, problem-solving

Prove that any integer greater than or equal to $7$ can be
written as a sum of two relatively prime integers, both
greater than $1$.For example, $22$ and $15$ are relatively
prime, and thus $37 = 22+15$ represents the number $37$
in the desired way

Comment: Can you find a general way to do any odd number? (Those are the easiest.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes n + n+1

Comment: i tried for even numbers what i did is write them in form of 7+k where k is not a multiple of 7

Comment: Choose $d\in[2,n-2]$, such that $\gcd(n,d)=1$, then $n=\color\red{d}+(\color\green{n-d})$.

Comment: @barakmanos how do we prove existence of such d in our set ?

Comment: The easiest way is to show that $\phi(n)>2$, so there must be such a $d$. Note that $\phi(3)=\phi(4)=\phi(6)=2$, so it is not true for $n=3,4,6$.

Comment: For odd numbers $N= (N-1)/2 + (N+1)/2$. Example $5=2+3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n=2k+1$ then $k,k+1$ are relatively prime.

If $n=4k$ then $2k-1,2k+1$ are relatively prime.

If $n=4k+2$ then $2k-1,2k+3$ are relatively prime.

Comment: The last two cases can be combined into $4k+2=(2k-3)+(2k+5)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews how do we find these pairs of relatively prime integers is there a particular method you used or you randomly picked them so that their sum is the required number and checked if they were relatively prime

Comment: Actually, $2k-1,2k+3$ also works. @GerryMyerson

Comment: @user347954 I did trial and error. After the odd case, I figured out the $4k$ case. Numbers which are close together are easier to prove to be relatively prime. As noted by a previous comment, it was actually easier to do the $4k+2$ cases all at once.

Comment: Edited to make the $4k+2$ case easier.